# How to display image with Tkinter from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I have a very simple program on `raspberry pi` to convert an image RGB to Greyscale and Binary using `OpenCV`,

**My Question**

I want to make an interface for my program but `OpenCV` isn't able to do so I
using `Tkinter` for this. So how can I show an image when I click `function` `bgr2grey` or `bgr2bi` the new picture will display replace an older picture.

**My Code**

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
def bgr2grey():
    img2 = cv2.imread("pexels-photo-709552.jpeg",0)
    resized_img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (240,150))
    imgGrey = resized_img2[::1]
    imgtk = Image.fromarray(imgGrey)
    imgTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgtk)
    lbl = Label(root, image=imgTk)
    lbl.pack()

def bgr2bi():
    img3 = cv2.imread("pexels-photo-709552.jpeg",0)
    (thresh, im_bi) = cv2.threshold(img3, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    resized_img3 = cv2.resize(im_bi, (240,150))
    imgBi = resized_img3[::1]
    imgtk = Image.fromarray(imgBi)
    imgTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgtk)
    lbl = Label(root, image=imgTk)
    lbl.pack()


img = cv2.imread("pexels-photo-709552.jpeg")
resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (240,150))
imgRGB = resized_img[:,:,::-1]
imgtk = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
imgTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgtk)
lbl = Label(root, image=imgTk)
lbl.pack()

root.title("Image") 
button_1 = Button(root, text="Convert RGB To Greyscale", command = bgr2grey)
button_1.pack()
button_2 = Button(root, text="Convert RGB To Binary", command = bgr2bi)
button_2.pack()

root.mainloop()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: There are over 100 opencv / tkinter questions on this site. Did you look at any of them to see if they could answer your question?

Comment: PIL / numpy can resize images and convert to grayscale or binary. opencv is overkill for this.